# Classes relation design

Tags: c#, class

I'm designing a class on an object and I have another class that has more characteristics and detail about the class in terms of something like class `Car` and `CarCharacteristicsRoad` for this class's specific characteristics/functions on the road for instance. The car class has like 10-20 functions and CarCharacteristicsRoad has like 10 more functions specific to this class on the road. I broke up the classes into two classes so I can manage this class.

So whenever CarCharacteristicsRoad is talked about, there should be a `Car`.

Should I use inherited class, sub class or any relation that I can restrict `CarCharacteristicsRoad` to `Car` object? Is there any restriction mechanism that I should use in C# so that it is more intuitive to assume that carcharateristicsroad is relative to car so that `CarCharacteristicsRoad` doesn't get thrown about in many different places like it is a higher level class (real object)

How would you design this?

Comment: If this were Java, I would 1) create an interface, ICharacteristicsRoad, and 2) create a subclass of "Car" that implements ICharacteristicsRoad.  In C++, I would probably just create a subclass.  It's your choice which you'd prefer in C#.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it there are 2 ways to go:

1. Use inheritance, as you have suggested - use this in case it is correct to say that `a car is a specific type of a CarCharacteristicsRoad` (wasn't that clear from your question...).
2. Pass a `car` instance to the constructor of `CarCharacteristicsRoad` (or even better an interface that the car implements, and by that implement the [DIP principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) ).

Answer (score 0):

I would make an abstract `Car` class and let a concrete class `RoadCar` extends the `Car` class. So you could use all methods from `Car` but could override them if needed. Let the `RoadCar` also implement the interface `IRoadCar` where you can specify the characteristics of a road car.

Also it could be useful to check out the [strategy pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html).